# Ranking values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has multiple budget records for a single ID each with a status, I need to be able to sum the budget and pull the status based on some predefined hierarchy. So if any of the records say "Forecast" for example, I need the sum to be marked as forecast.

```
ID      Status       Budget
1       Forecast     50
1       Forecast     100
1       Final        50
2       Final        75
2       Final        75
```

I would need the above table to return:

```
1 forecast 200
2 final 150
```

Ideally I would be able to add 3 or 4 levels into this hierarchy, but only the two are completely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a group by clause:

```
SELECT ID, Status, sum(Budget) forecast --this aliases the sum column so it's called "forcast" in query results
FROM your_table
 --WHERE status like 'Forecast%' --commented out this line but you may want it to limit the rows utilized in the sum.
GROUP BY ID, Status
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```